# Does 'could' in this context always refer to the past?

Tags: grammar

"I couldn't understand this."

Is that more polite than saying "I can't understand?"

Comment: The use of the modals 'could' and 'would' as a hedging device is well known. Look at this progression: Shut the XXXX window! Shut that window! Shut the window, John. Shut the window, please. Shut the window, please, John. Shut the window, would you, John. Will you shut the window, John. Will you kindly shut the window, John. Would you please shut the window, John. Do you think you could just shut the window for me, please, John(?)

Comment: It seems like a good question for [ell.se]

Answer (score 3):

- I can't understand him is Present Tense. Now you don't understand him
- I couldn't understand him is Past Tense. You speak of some time in the past.
  -"could" can be normal Past Tense and also Past subjunctive.
- Could* you help me please. - (could* means Past subjunctive). Though the form is Past, it is a form of politeness and referring to now.